# Capture KeyDown or KeyPress in .NET MAUI (Windows)

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I am working on a barcode reader app for Android and Windows. On Android, I receive a system broadcast for every barcode scanned, but on Windows the typical configuration is a keyboard entry sent from the barcode scanner. So what I am trying to do is capture the KeyDown/KeyPress event so that I can add all characters received into a temporary string and then submit to my app as a "barcode read event" as soon as "Enter" is received.

However, I am unable to find KeyDown/KeyPressed events in any of the controls. Is that possible at all? If so, where do I look? The closest (I think) I have gotten is this description of how to use the App lifecycle events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Thanks and best regards,

Joerg.

Comment: Desktop-like keyboard support does not yet exist; this would be part of [open proposal: Global Key Hooks](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739). FOR NOW, have you tried creating a page with an [`Entry`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry), clicking on that `Entry`, then using the scanner? If the scanner and bluetooth are set up, Keys should be received by the focused view. Entry's `TextChanged` event may be helpful. Google for similar questions related to `Xamarin.Forms` or `Xamarin.Android`; you can use any technique that worked for those.

Comment: Thank you @ToolmakerSteve, I did in fact use an `Entry` as a workaround in the meantime, but I still wondered if there was a way to actually capture the KeyPress anywhere in the app, without depending on the focus item. Your proposal confirms there is not (for the moment), so that answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Same issue here.  I'm trying to capture the P1, P2, or F1 to F12 keys but TextChanged doesn't fire.  I'm wondering if there is something available from Zebra DataWedge.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an `Entry` you don't need to read all keys, instead you can subscribe to `Completed` event witch is fired when `Enter` is readed into the Entry.

So many barcode readers can be configured to insert `Enter` as last part of barcode readed.

```
MyBarcodeReader()
{ 
    MyBarCodeEntry.Completed += MyBarCodeEntry_Completed;
}

private void MyBarCodeEntry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /// Do your JOB
}
```

**EDIT JUL 8 2023:**

Unfortunately the Completed event appears to be unpredictable and this was causing false positive reading. So I had to change my approach and decided to add a listener to my Entry binding source and analize if the results ends with an \r. This solve all my false positives.

Something like this

```
public static readonly BindableProperty FilterProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Filter), typeof(string), typeof(QuickSearch), null, propertyChanged: OnFilterChanged);
public string Filter
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FilterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FilterProperty, value); }
}
private static async void OnFilterChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if (bindable is QuickSearch q)
        await q.ProccessFilter();
}

private void ProccessFilter()
{
    CapturedCode = Filter?.Replace("\r", "") ?? string.Empty;
    Regex regex = new(SearchParms.RegexTemplate);
    if (Filter == null || regex.IsMatch((string)CapturedCode))
    {
        if (Filter != null && Filter.EndsWith("\r"))
            await ProccessCodeCompleted();
        return;
    }
}
```

Maybe this is caused by maui bugs. (Maui is a pretty good tool but still so buggy)

Comment: Thank you @juan-pablo-gomez. I am aware of this, but the idea was to not have to use an Entry control at all... Sorry for maybe not being explicit enough...

Comment: @Joerg Do you have any news with your approach?

Comment: To work around this issue I resorted to adding an `Entry` control visible just on Windows Platforms...

Comment: @Joerg Be carefull with COMPLETED event I'm experiencing troubles on some custmer machines making totally impreditcable COMPLETED be fired, see EDIT

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the [UIElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement?view=winrt-22621) on which the key pressed events should be detected from [Handler.PlatformView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.handlers.viewhandler.platformview?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-handlers-viewhandler-platformview). And then hook up the native events.

```
var handler = mauiView.Handler;
UIElement? nativeView = handler?.PlatformView as UIElement;
if (nativeView != null)
{
    nativeView.KeyDown += this.PlatformView_KeyDown;
    nativeView.KeyUp += this.PlatformView_KeyUp;
    nativeView.PreviewKeyDown += this.PlatformView_PreviewKeyDown;
}
```

Here, `mauiView` is the view on which the key pressed events should be detected. Please note that this view should be focused for the key pressed events to be detected.

Comment: you cant use UIElement by default in maui, did you forgot to reference a library or package?

Comment: @Barreto, The type "UIElement" is a native WinUI class. The entire code I shared should be enclosed within the #if WINDOWS directive. No additional package needed.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard accelerators are in MAUI .NET 8.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/keyboard-accelerators?view=net-maui-8.0

[image: menubar.png]

A KeyboardAccelerator can be attached to a MenuFlyoutItem by adding it to its KeyboardAccelerators collection:

```xml
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Cut"
                Clicked="OnCutMenuFlyoutItemClicked">
    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Ctrl"
                             Key="X" />
    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
</MenuFlyoutItem>
```

Keyboard accelerators can also be specified in code:

```cs
cutMenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators.Add(new KeyboardAccelerator
{
    Modifiers = KeyboardAcceleratorModifiers.Ctrl,
    Key = "X"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For windows it is better to hook into the native keyboard system, which makes sure you always receive input.

When using an Entry you're never sure that an entry has focus and is capable of receiving input.

A great tool for this is [SharpHook](https://github.com/TolikPylypchuk/SharpHook).