Basic example of how to capture pressed keys in dotNet Maiu
I need a basic example, where when pressing the enter key, my code performs an action in my code, for example click on a button or call some function.
I tried using the SharpHook library, but I couldn't find any examples of how to do this, I'm desperate for a solution.
Below I will put the standard example code that is generated by dotnet maiu when creating a project, so my desire is that when I press the enter key it triggers the counter button simulating my clicking on the button, I don't mind using a third-party library, as long as you have an example to understand how it works.
namespace ExampleKeysIndiFarma
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;

            if (count == 1)
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
            else
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

            SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
        }
    }

}


Do you need something like this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319655/capture-keydown-or-keypress-in-net-maui-windows/75821156#75821156
Note. its only for windows
